# Удаление повторяющихся символов (&<>"'\/;:%^?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Нужно удалить указанные символы при вводе в поле.

Делаю вот так

```
$('#tochange').bind("change keyup paste input", function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[&<>"'\/;:%^?]/,""));
});
```

Но если вставлять несколько одинаковых, например, `'''''''''::::` то некоторая их часть остаётся и потом стирается в процессе ввода, как быть?

Comment: "стирается" или "не стирается" ?

Comment: @Igor стирается частями, некоторые остаются

Comment: @Rufex, кстати, получать несколько раз значение `$(this)` в одном и том же обработчике довольно расточительно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавьте модификатор global (`g`):

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[&<>"'\/;:%^?]/g,""));
```

Это будет заменять все указанные знаки не один раз, а по всей длине данного текста...